# Can't inject document with Angular Universal after update

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

We are using Angular Universal for server-side-rendering. After an upgrade from Angular 8 to 10 there is a run time error in a service, that injects the document abstraction:

```
export class FooService {
^
ReferenceError: Document is not defined
```

The code:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
...
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FooService {
...

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { ... }
```

How can I correctly inject the document abstraction as it has worked before in Angular 8?

Update: this is my tsconfig.server.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app-server",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es2016",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

Comment: This should still work. My guess is your issue is purely typing related. You could check this by changing document: Document with document: any. Basically your are assuming a type Document is available..

Comment: @MikeOne you are right. At the server no typing of libdom.d.ts (the ones without import) is working. But why?

Comment: I think it's because the dom lib is not imported server side (check `tsconfig.server.json` vs `tsconfig.app.json`)

Comment: @David the server config extends the app config, even putting the libs explicitly does not make any difference, I updated my post with the config.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I actually upgraded one of my apps to angular 10 and compiled it with SSR, using `Document` type and *without* the dom lib in `tsconfig.server.json`, and I did not have this error. So it must be something else